# GCP KMS Signing JWT using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-cloud-kms

I am new to GCP, I created RSA_SIGN_PKCS1_2048_SHA256 for ASYMMETRIC_SIGN purpose.

Now I have to sign a JWT header and payload before I send request to another Webservice(which already has my Public key).

**JWT Header**

```
 {
        "alg": RS256
        "kid": xx
        "typ": JWT
    }
```

**JWT Assertion**

```
  {
            "iss": xxx,
            "sub": xxx,
            "aud": xxx
            "token.aud":xx,
            "iat": int(created_time.timestamp()),
            "exp": int(expiry_time.timestamp())
}
```

**GCP Signing method**

```
def sign_asymmetric(project_id, location_id, key_ring_id, key_id, version_id, message):
    """
    Sign a message using the public key part of an asymmetric key.

    Args:
        project_id (string): Google Cloud project ID (e.g. 'my-project').
        location_id (string): Cloud KMS location (e.g. 'us-east1').
        key_ring_id (string): ID of the Cloud KMS key ring (e.g. 'my-key-ring').
        key_id (string): ID of the key to use (e.g. 'my-key').
        version_id (string): Version to use (e.g. '1').
        message (string): Message to sign.

    Returns:
        AsymmetricSignResponse: Signature.
    """

    from google.cloud import kms
    import base64
    import hashlib

    client = kms.KeyManagementServiceClient()


    key_version_name = client.crypto_key_version_path(project_id, location_id, key_ring_id, key_id, version_id)

    message_bytes = message.encode('utf-8') 
    hash_ = hashlib.sha256(message_bytes).digest()
    digest = {'sha256': hash_}

    sign_response = client.asymmetric_sign(
        request={'name': key_version_name, 'digest': digest})

  
    print('Signature: {}'.format(base64.b64encode(sign_response.signature)))
    return sign_response
```

So how do I pass my JWT header and JWT Assertion to this method as it expects only message as input argument.

**JWT_encode -** what will be my JWT encode ( Previous I used my Private key (stored locally)and constructed my JTW_encode using  JWT.encode method and passed my payload, header, algo and private key and it worked fine.) Now we are using GCP KMS so not sure how to do this

```
request_body = {
            "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
            "assertion": JWT_encode,
            "client_id": "xxx"
        }
```

I wanted to know how to construct my assertion in the request body.

Comment: message = base64.b64encode(JWT Header) + '.' + base64.b64encode(JWT Assertion) signed_jwt = message + '.' + sign_asymmetric(...,, message)

Comment: you might need some Python string encode()/decode() functions depending on whether you need strings or bytes.

Comment: Hi we cannot concat that way as it is not string but bytes

Comment: Did you read my second comment?

Comment: You do realize that you can use b'.' to concatenate bytes? Example: **b'hello' + b'.' + b'world'**

Comment: Sorry. I missed that. Thank you John. Much Appreciated. It worked. I will post the answer too.

Comment: Happy to help with your question.